# How to get a package installed on an Ubuntu 18.04 when internet is not working

Tags: apt, 18.04, internet

I freshly installed Kubuntu 18.04. Neither availble wireless or wired connections are possible or even shown up. I found recommondation to install proprietary driver package  bcmwl-kernel-source via apt. How can I do this without having access to internet on that machine? I have same system installed freshly on a second machine with working wifi.

Tried out given answer, but while having correct checksums i get the following error:

```
drsnuggles@DrSnugglesLaboratory:~/Downloads$ sha1sum /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/*
6597a27d6fe69bc9aad2a934e90b64a40949f893  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
c7b26a0e9b086afdcd81bb02a4cbe12646dade91  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
aa73940acee518d1201f7f03f8e471c3546da489  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9_all.deb
5aabcfc6381dcbd005200c0f27e1ecd9f95339b4  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/dpkg-dev_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb
78bd55a38243cf1b0f5550149a76032428f603cb  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/fakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
98d89e48ca219bdee6f7d618a1a36db703bd3ac0  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/g++_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
194c6c5f50cabd7cd8d5680143a6335224ee1abe  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/g++-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
a508abdf3f9ceeb09d65daeca63871225792a3b4  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/gcc_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb
d3805cffc3ce54d85144b4bf6841d024964a996e  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/gcc-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
787fadec1dbb5d6775d76126090d502946a1b7fc  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-1_all.deb
2fa938adbdda45393740b7c1d146367657aec4f6  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-5_amd64.deb
869e827a5cd5d7951de2b9f20e3fa29c69fc8bc5  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb
b6d3552f6e43cfee7ae3e455394e4303b958bde9  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libasan4_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
5413fc08d8dbf76f49276f14c06a965967a0a53d  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libatomic1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
7b948442903694a1211c96809b8f17ca0be542a0  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libc6-dev_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libcilkrts5_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libgcc-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libitm1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/liblsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libmpx2_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libquadmath0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libstdc++-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libtsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/libubsan0_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-39.42_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  /home/drsnuggles/Downloads/manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb
drsnuggles@DrSnugglesLaboratory:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
(Reading database ... 181033 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) over (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9) over (2.3-3ubuntu9) ...
Preparing to unpack dpkg-dev_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) over (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack fakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.22-2ubuntu1) over (1.22-2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack g++_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2) over (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack g++-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-7 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) over (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc_7.3.0-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2) over (4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc-7_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-7 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) over (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) over (1.19.03-1) ...
Preparing to unpack libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-5) over (0.04-5) ...
Preparing to unpack libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) over (0.08-3) ...
Preparing to unpack libasan4_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan4:amd64 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) over (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack libatomic1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatomic1:amd64 (8-20180414-1ubuntu2) over (8-20180414-1ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack libc6-dev_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1) over (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb: error: 'libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libcilkrts5_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libcilkrts5_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libgcc-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libgcc-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libitm1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libitm1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'liblsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive liblsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libmpx2_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libmpx2_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libquadmath0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libquadmath0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libstdc++-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libstdc++-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libtsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libtsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'libubsan0_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive libubsan0_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-39.42_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-39.42_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb: error: 'manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bcmwl-kernel-source:
 bcmwl-kernel-source depends on linux-libc-dev; however:
  Package linux-libc-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of build-essential:
 build-essential depends on make; however:
  Package make is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package build-essential (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dkms:
 dkms depends on make | build-essential; however:
  Package make is not installed.
  Package build-essential is not configured yet.
 dkms depends on patch; however:
  Package patch is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dkms (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dpkg-dev:
 dpkg-dev depends on libdpkg-perl (= 1.19.0.5ubuntu2); however:
  Package libdpkg-perl is not installed.
 dpkg-dev depends on patch (>= 2.7); however:
  Package patch is not installed.
 dpkg-dev depends on make; however:
  Package make is not installed.
 dpkg-dev depends on binutils; however:
  Package binutils is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dpkg-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fakeroot:
 fakeroot depends on libfakeroot (>= 1.22-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libfakeroot is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package fakeroot (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-7:
 g++-7 depends on libstdc++-7-dev (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3); however:
  Package libstdc++-7-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package g++-7 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-7:
 gcc-7 depends on binutils (>= 2.30); however:
  Package binutils is not installed.
 gcc-7 depends on libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3); however:
  Package libgcc-7-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-7 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-5) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up libasan4:amd64 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (8-20180414-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:amd64:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package libc-dev-bin is not installed.
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on linux-libc-dev; however:
  Package linux-libc-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++:
 g++ depends on g++-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~); however:
  Package g++-7 is not configured yet.
 g++ depends on gcc-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~); however:
  Package gcc-7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package g++ (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc:
 gcc depends on gcc-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~); however:
  Package gcc-7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 libcilkrts5_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
 libfakeroot_1.22-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 libgcc-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
 libitm1_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 liblsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 libmpx2_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 libquadmath0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 libstdc++-7-dev_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
 libtsan0_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
 libubsan0_7.3.0-16ubuntu3_amd64.deb
 linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-39.42_amd64.deb
 make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 manpages-dev_4.15-1_all.deb
 bcmwl-kernel-source
 build-essential
 dkms
 dpkg-dev
 fakeroot
 g++-7
 gcc-7
 libc6-dev:amd64
 g++
 gcc
```

Comment: Do you still have the install DVD, USB or SD card from which you installed Ubuntu? Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required packages for `bcmwl-kernel-source` can be shown by simulating the `apt install` command...

```
apt -s install bcmwl-kernel-source
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
.
.
.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source build-essential dkms dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libfakeroot
  libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
```

You will need all of the packages listed under "The following NEW packages will be installed."

On the computer with Internet access, download all of these packages. Here are all the URLs to make things easier for you...

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bcmwl-kernel-source
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dkms
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dpkg-dev
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fakeroot
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/g++
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/g++-7
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gcc-7
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libalgorithm-diff-perl
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libalgorithm-merge-perl
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libasan4
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libatomic1
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libc-dev-bin
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libc6-dev
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libcilkrts5
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfakeroot
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgcc-7-dev
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libitm1
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/liblsan0
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmpx2
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libquadmath0
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libstdc++-7-dev
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libtsan0
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libubsan0
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-libc-dev
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/make
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/manpages-dev

Scroll down on each page, and click on the architecture for the package you need (probably amd64). On the next page, select one of the mirrors closest to you (for example, http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb).

Download each *.deb file.

After you've downloaded all of the *.deb files, copy them to your computer without Internet access using a thumb-drive.

Then, install the packages using...

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

(You may need to run the above command a few times until all dependency packages are installed, and `bcmwl-kernel-source` can be installed without error).

Comment: I could not make your solution work, see my extended question which I modified.

Comment: I don't think your check-sums are correct. You need to use the command `sha1sum --check <check_sum_filename>` to verify the checksum. You can also use `sha1sum <filename.deb> | grep <check_sum value>`. For example, your checksum for `libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` is `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` according to your output. But when I go to the download URL (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libc-dev-bin/download), at the bottom o the page, it says the SHA1 checksum should be `87505b56c7d40de5c5c7368a8853bd881ab6bb84`.

Comment: One more thing,.. fourteen of your downloaded files have the exact same checksum `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709`. Did you accidentally overwrite the same file with different names? Is your USB drive OK? What is the check sum of the file on the computer with internet access? Does it match the "SHA1 checksum" value shown at the bottom of the package's download page? After you copy the file to the computer without internet access, is the checksum still the same?

Comment: I realized as well after forum posting, that indeed files have been corrupt. I downloaded again and had to add other packages. Was quite a pain, but it worked in the end. Accepted the answer and thanks.

Comment: And did you extract in your answer the URLs with a bash loop? Would be nice to have in the answer. I cannot image you clicked for this like half an hour :d.

Comment: The issue is that the final download links contain the package versions appended to the file name. Even if you assume the same mirror for all the files, it would be a manual process to figure out all of the current versions suffixes for all of these files. I guess you could do use `apt search` to get the correct version numbers, but then you would have to parse each `apt search` result, probably using `sed`. Although it would be nice to have some kind of script, by the time you're done debugging it, you could have just clicked through all of the links.