# How to Install Wifi Driver without Internet

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I am trying to install ubuntu on a laptop with no internet connectivity except for Wifi. I found this https://ibcomputing.com/install-wifi-driver-broadcom-bcm43142-linux/amp/ but I don't see a way to find and install the drivers from a disk (USB drive). Older questions relating to this have broken links or incomplete instructions.

I'm also not sure what file format I should be looking for to download: the options I found on packages.ubuntu.com seem to be *.tar.xz, *.tar.dz, or *.dcs - when I try to use them in dpkg I just gat the error that they are not a valid format. Do I need to unpack them? are there files inside I should be looking for? Sorry if this part of the question is pretty basic.

Edit: I don't think the problem is the driver. Ubuntu detects my Wifi card correctly, and includes the proprietary drive. It just doesn't allow me to use it.

Comment: Do you still have the installation DVD or USB? Check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949

Comment: I think that I understand the process described here but I imagine I should start here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/broadcom-sta as this is the driver I need for my Wifi? Or is this for all wifi? I am currently running from the USB Drive "Live" system - do I need to install it before I can access these additional files?

Comment: If you are running from the live USB, look under Software and Updates, then under Additional Drivers. Install the driver offered. Then install Ubuntu and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I was able to download the correct *.deb files from packages.ubuntu.com and dependencies, namely broadcom-sta-dkms, dkms, and libiw-30. I used "sudo dpkg" for each of them after transferring them to the computer manually. After no errors and a couple restarts, now it is working like a charm. Thanks!