# Lubuntu does not find Wi-Fi (and I cannot connect to the internet by wire)

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, internet

I just installed Lubuntu 20.04 on an old Toshiba laptop (model is SATELLITE C40-C-10K) and it cannot find any Wi-Fi connection. It couldn't find a Wi-Fi connection also while I was on live boot, but I thought, it will find a connection when I install Lubuntu. I found several solutions on the internet, but they all require a wired connection. That's the problem, this laptop does not have a LAN port, therefore I cannot connect an internet cable to it.

Is there any way to connect to WiFi (assuming I still want Lubuntu on this laptop)?

I would also like to point out that I am a beginner when it comes to linux.

Thanks in advance

Edit: @chili555, I used the command `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and this is the output:

```
02:00.0 "0280" "14e4" "4365" -r01 "1b9a" "3002"
03:00.0 "ff00" "10ec" "5229" -r01 "1179" "f80b"
```

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Not all WiFi hardware is supported by Linux out of the box. @chilli555 approach might help us to identify the right steps, once we know your hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the result of the terminal command should be much more. Please double-check.

However, the abbreviated result you posted suggests that your wireless device is 14e4:4365, a Broadcom device. There are three options that you can use to install the driver.

First, and easiest, is to tether your phone to get a temporary internet connection. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The second option is that the driver and all its dependencies are present on the installation USB. Reinstall and be sure to select the option to install third-party software:

[image]

The third option is tedious but workable and is described here: [Unable to use wifi card 16.04 MacOS dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949)

Comment: Well the result of the terminal is nothing more than these two lines, but I think it doesn't matter as the first solution you wrote worked perfectly. Thank you very much :D